# Unable to build static lib of mesa (libGL.a)

Tags: gcc, xorg, mesa, meson-build

Trying to build a static library of libGL. Looking at "meson configure", it states that static libraries are default. Still, I only end up with a libGL.so file. Is the any magic voodoo to get the static version to compile? Only answers I find online is for old version of mesa that still used the standard "./configure; make"

Comment: Try this: go to [src/glx/meson.build to line 161](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/anholt/mesa/blob/master/src/glx/meson.build#L161) and change `shared_library` into `static_library`. But if it doesn't work, you have all dependencies listed there, so you would have to extract the `.a` archives and pack them together into `libGL.a`

Comment: @KamilCuk That worked! Thanks! I wonder why there are no standard parameters to do this though? Seems odd to manually edit the build-file.

Comment: Well, hm, in `configure` scripts you specified  (many) options using the command line. I believe they could script it manually and add like `if (BUILD_GL_AS_STATIC_LIBRARY)`, but nowadays build process becomes much more complicated and much more complex. Configure script is nice for a one project, but currently people work with many projects and subprojects and subsubprojects all linked together... So I think that's why it get's easier to edit the build files of a proper project rather then specify thousand of options on the command line.

Comment: I think the use of `shared_library` is just wrong. It should use `library`, which allows the user to control what gets built using `-Ddefault_library=static` or `-Ddefault_library=both`. I have fixed similar problems upstream [in gtk](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/2248) and [`at-spi2-atk`](https://github.com/GNOME/at-spi2-atk/pull/1).

Comment: @DanieleTesta I cannot reproduce your results to produce `libGL.a`. Which mesa version did you use, and with which meson flags? Thanks!

Comment: @nh2 19.2.2 with no flags, just "meson".

Comment: @DanieleTesta Thanks; I managed now; I had switched to `library` as mentioned above, but then found that for mesa for now `-Ddefault_library=both` does not work (but `-Ddefault_library=static` did). I will try to upstream that change.

Comment: @nh2 Then you might also want to change the help output which states static lib is built by default, which clearly is not the case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile libGL as a static library, change the line `161` inside [src/glx/meson.build](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/anholt/mesa/blob/master/src/glx/meson.build#L161) from `shared_library` to `static_library`.

Comment: That is not enough. You also need to remove the "version" parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know about the version thing Daniele mentioned. I did not have to remove it. But I did change it to `library` instead of `static_library` because it allows us to choose which one we want. Or both. By the way, apparently this ugly hack seems to be the only way to build it as a static library. [The devs seem to have no idea why they are forcing it to be a shared library](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/2012)

Comment: I meant that you need to remove the "version" param if you change from shared_library to static_library. If you change to just "library", you can probably choose with the -Ddefault_library config param.